# Disable HTML Link after it has been Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am trying to disable a link that submits my form after it has been clicked. This is needed to stop duplicate requests from the same user. Here is my code, but unfortunately it is not working.

```
<a id="submit-form-link" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()" class="next">Next <span>Step</span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit-form-link').click(function(){
        $('submit-form-link', this).attr('style', 'pointer-events: none;');
    });
</script>
```

I feel like I am close but it just is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about this wrong. Get rid of the inline onclick event handler and use this inside a document ready call:

```
$('#submit-form-link').one('click', function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

This binds the click event to your link, but unbinds it after the first click.

You can see this in the console in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qwUbm/)**. The first time you click the link it attempts to submit the form, but doesn't try on subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
$('submit-form-link').off().click(function() { return false; });
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="submit-form-link" onclick="document.forms[0].submit()" class="next">Next <span>Step</span></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit-form-link').click(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            $('submit-form-link', this).attr('class', 'next disabled');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Here, you can create a class `disabled` and style it as you want. Just add this class after clicking the button so you will know that it is disabled. Then you return false to stop the event if the button was already clicked.

Answer (score 0):

bind the click event again in the first click event callback function

```
$('#submit-form-link').click(function(){
    $('submit-form-link', this).attr('style', 'pointer-events: none;');

     $(this).click(function(e){e.preventDefault})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `onclick` attribute.

```
$('#submit-form-link').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

Also, `$('submit-form-link', this)` is totally wrong. You are selecting nodes of type `submit-form-link` that are children of `this`. First of all you'd need `#submit-form-link` and second `this` is already a reference to the link node you just clicked.